# how to convert play.api.libs.json.JsValue to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework, play-json

how to convert play jsObject to JSONObject?

example :

```
val samplePlayJson = Json.obj(
  "name" -> "Watership Down",
  "location" -> Json.obj("lat" -> 51.235685, "long" -> -1.309197),
  "residents" -> Json.arr(
    Json.obj(
      "name" -> "Fiver",
      "age" -> 4,
      "role" -> JsNull
    ),
    Json.obj(
      "name" -> "Bigwig",
      "age" -> 6,
      "role" -> "Owsla"
    )
  )
)
```

when I tired to pass above `samplePlayJson` to a Java api that accepts  JSONObject I got type mismatch error

```
type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.JsObject
 required: org.json.JSONObject
```

how to convert above samplePlayJson to `org.json.JSONObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `play.api.libs.json.JsObject` to string and make `org.json.JSONObject` out of it. I didn't find any direct methods to do so.

```
new JSONObject(samplePlayJson.toString())
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing the same thing as a workaround.